# Is there any good example of use cases for angular.identity()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, angularjs

According to the documentation

```
A function that returns its first argument. This function is useful when writing code in the functional style.
```

I am wondering where I can find a good example of such use case - writing code in functional style in an angular app. 
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example from the AngularJS source code:

```
function transformer(transformationFn, value) {
  return (transformationFn || angular.identity)(value);
};
```

Explanation:

In case `transformationFn` is provided as first parameter, it will be called with `value` as it's own parameter. Otherwise `identity` function will be called with the same value.

As ng source code mentions:

> *This function is useful when writing code in the functional style.*

What this means is that in functional programming there are no globals, so you always have to pass/inject in everything you need.

Comment: I didn't understand why we call `angular.identity()` function (when transformationFn is undefined) and what it does on calling.

Comment: It's basically used here as a default implementation - when no transformation function is supplied, just fall back to the identity (ie. no transformation).

Answer (score 9):

Lets say we have these two below functions:

```
$scope.square = function(n) {
return n * n
};


$scope.multplybyTwo = function(n) {
return n * 2
};
```

To call this in a functional way:

```
$scope.givemeResult = function(fn, val) {
return (fn || angular.identity)(val);
};
```

Then You may use the above function something like below:

```
$scope.initVal = 5;
$scope.squareResult = $scope.givemeResult($scope.square, $scope.initVal);
$scope.intoTwo = $scope.givemeResult($scope.multplybyTwo, $scope.initVal);
```

You may follow the below link:

http://litutech.blogspot.in/2014/02/angularidentity-example.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://stackoverflow.com/about), not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that this

```
function transformer(transformationFn, value) {
  return (transformationFn || angular.identity)(value);
};
```

could be "un-refactored" to this

```
function transformer(transformationFn, value) {
  if (transformationFn) {
    return transformationFn(value);
  } else {
    return angular.identity(value);
  }
};
```

which would be functionally equivalent to this `identity`-less version:

```
function transformer(transformationFn, value) {
  if (transformationFn) {
    return transformationFn(value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
};
```

So I guess the use case would be when you want to apply a certain transformation to a value when you're supplied with something that may or may not actually exist.

I wanted to better explain the `identity` function (as I understand it), although as I review my answer I don't think I really answered your question. Leaving my answer here anyway in case it's helpful.

Comment: A clear explanation of what angular.identity acually does, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`angular.identity` is useful for cases where you want to reference an object bound to a parent by passing it from a parent to its children.

> An identity function is like the zero for functions. Kind of useless by itself, but occasionally useful as part of an expression using higher-order functions, where you can take a function as a parameter or return it as a result.

Here is an example for array values:

> For example, you may bind a two-dimensional array to an initial selection, and then bind the contained inner arrays to each subselection. The values function in this case is the identity function: it is invoked for each group of child elements, being passed the data bound to the parent element, and returns this array of data.

Use it when it is necessary to pass a dummy function to:

- a promise ($q)
- a compiler ($compile)
- a unit test (spy/mock)

which acts as a data source or pump for a pipe|filter.

By comparison, `Angular.noop` incorrectly handles resolving/rejecting promises correctly because it always returns undefined, whereas `Angular.identity` correctly handles resolving/rejecting promises because it always returns the argument passed to it( `f(x) = x` ).

In terms of constructors in Angular, it is relevant as such:

> JavaScript engines only return the instance of a constructor if the constructor does not explicitly return an object (i.e. a value of the type object or function). Hence new identity(value) is always an object. Thus new identity(value) == value only returns true if value is an object. This is because the equality operators in JavaScript always check for identity when one of the operands is an object.

**References**

- [Purpose of an 'Identity Function'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298627/1113772)
- [What is Angular.noop used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348253/1113772)
- [What is the practical use of the identity function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108835/1113772)
- [What do people use the identity function for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987085/1113772)
- [Use of the identity function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485508/1113772)
- [Where and why is identity function useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504350/1113772)
- [How do I pretty print an XSLT result document with removed source elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228004/1113772)
- [d3 wiki: Selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections)
- [AngularJS Issue #4579: orderBy filter doesn't support sorting by the value itself](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4579)
- [Promises and the danger of angular.noop](http://www.codeducky.org/promises-danger-angular-noop/)
- [The Identity Monad](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/cl-monad-macros/monad-macros.htm#_Toc251846355)
- [Function composition and the identity function](http://www.kevinalbrecht.com/code/joy-mirror/j02maf.html)
- [Cocoa Drawing Guide: Transforms - The Identity Transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-SW8)
- [Understanding Fluent APIs](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-like-boss-understanding-fluent-apis/)
- [Please explain usage of _.identity(value) of underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216479/)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256090/function-only-returns-unchanged-parameter-useless