# What is Angular.noop used for?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried searching it everywhere even on [Angular.org](http://Angular.org) documentation but couldn't find any detailed explanation with implementation. It would be hugely helpful if any could explain it.

Comment: it's just an empty function that does nothing

Comment: That much I got already. But why do we use it like this? 
"success = success || angular.noop;"

Comment: looks like @lechariotdor has got the better answer...you might move your acceptance so visitors to this page are more quickly directed to the best answer

Answer (score 151, accepted):

angular.noop is an empty function that can be used as a placeholder when you need to pass some function as a param.

```
function foo (callback) {
    // Do a lot of complex things

    callback();
}

// Those two have the same effect, but the later is more elegant
foo(function() {});
foo(angular.noop);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of calling `noop` rather than just leaving the function blank?  Aesthetics, performance or something else?

Comment: @abyrne85 It is more aesthetically pleasing and a good practice to use `angular.noop` as you always reuse the same empty function (instead of declaring a new anonymous function everytime). Performance-wise it makes no difference as the code for `angular.noop` is just an empty function named `noop`.

Comment: Using angular.noop creates a strong coupling with angular object. I do prefer using inline anonymous function when is necessary.

Comment: Great thanks :) Can you explain what is $timeout(angular.noop)?

Answer (score 27):

I find it extremely helpful when writing a function that expects a callback.

Example:

```
function myFunction(id, value, callback) {

    // some logic
    return callback(someData);
}
```

The function above will return an error, when it gets called without specifying the third argument. `myFunction(1, 'a');`

Example (using `angular.noop`):

```
function myFunction(id, value, callback) {

    var cb = callback || angular.noop; // if no `callback` provided, don't break :)
    // some logic
    return cb(someData);
}
```

Comment: Or you have a one-liner for that : `typeof callback === 'function' && callback();`. Way more classy ^^. Not using `angular.noop` though.

Answer (score 16):

It is a function that performs no operations. This is useful in situation like this:

```
function foo(y) {
   var x= fn();
   (y|| angular.noop)(x);
 }
```

It is useful when writing code in the functional style

Comment: Ok. Got it thanks. But just a little query that why can't we simply do "(y)(x)" instead of "(y|| angular.noop)(x);"? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @AngularHarsh:- You may write that. May be this example will help:- `//do nothing on the success callback, hence replacing the success callbck function with angular.noop()`
 $scope.contacts= Contacts.query( angular.noop,function(response) {
            Window.myresp = response;
            $scope.displayError(response);
            console.log("bad boy, listContacts failed");
  });

Comment: I think I got it now. So what we are doing here is displayError is triggered on failure but nothing happens on success(as suggested).

Answer (score 5):

*this answer assumes that u are not a beginner in angular

Angular.noop is an empty function that can be used as placeholder in some cases

for example:

Imagine you are using q.all which do multiple calls to the api and return one promise.
If some of these calls fail but u still need to handle the ones that didnt fail, use angular noop as a callback to the api calls when u catch the calls.
If u dont use angular noop, q.all will reject everthing if one call fails.

Q.all( somecall.catch(angular.noop), anothercall).then( resolve result[0] and result[1])

If a call fails, Angular will ignore that and perform another call (but u will still will undefined for the first resolved result)

I Hope that I helped

Comment: I downvoted because your answer is so grammatically and formally wrong I couldn't actually get any reliable information from it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = (callback || angular.noop)(params)
```

Its a shortest way to do

```
var result = typeof callback === 'function' && callback(params);
```

Taking into account that callback var will be a function

Comment: this is elegant

Answer (score 2):

If you want official documentation here is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop). It is pretty simple. I have also pasted the current documentation from link.

---

**A function that performs no operations. This function can be useful when writing code in the functional style.**

```
function foo(callback) {
  var result = calculateResult();
  (callback || angular.noop)(result);
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Trick: You can also use it to add a ternary to an `ng-click` attribute:

```
ng-click="(variable) ? doSomething() : angular.noop()"
```

<sub><sub>Until I found out you could use ng-click="variable && doSomething()"`</sub></sub>

Comment: `ng-click="(variable) ? doSomething() : true"` would also work

Comment: ng-click="(variable) ? doSomething() : '' " would also work