# Use of noop function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the ng-form directive there is a function named noop(). What is the use of this function? How can I guess the use of this function?

Comment: The SO [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/3032/built-in-helper-functions/12274/angular-noop#t=201705201835575849653) guide will help you

Comment: it could be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348253/what-is-angular-noop-used-for

Comment: it will help you visit:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348253/what-is-angular-noop-used-for

Answer (score 0):

You can find it's use in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop).

> A function that performs no operations. This function can be useful when writing code in the functional style.