# Is there an angular.noop for Angular 6?

Tags: angular, no-op

In my Angular 6 application, I need a function that does nothing. Obviously, I could just write my own, but I was reading about angular.noop which I would like to use. However, I get an `angular.noop is not a function` error when I try to use it. I could not find anything about this in Angular's documentation. Is there an Angular 6 version of AngularJS's angular.noop function?

I know what noop is. This is not a duplicate of [What is Angular.noop used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348253/what-is-angular-noop-used-for). I am asking about Angular 6. My question is very simply "Is there a noop function built into Angular 6 like there is in AngularJS?".

Comment: Please show in the question how you want to use that function.

Comment: @ConnorsFan What difference does it make? All I want to know is if there is an equivalent function in Angular 6.

Comment: @SiddAjmera No, I saw that. I know what the function is. That question is for AngularJS. Mine is regarding Angular 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is not a noop function in Angular 6.

Answer (score 20):

You could use **[`noop`](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/helpers/noop.html)** which is a helper function from `Rxjs` for this:

```
import { noop } from 'rxjs';
...
// this does nothing.
noop();
```

I don't really think Angular has `noop`

Answer (score 4):

This does nothing:

```
()=>{}
```

It's no more characters than noop() and doesn't need an import.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to use this with `(click)`. Try:

```
(click)="!!false"
```

it works and the compiler doesn't complain. Maybe there is a more semantic solution.