# What does identity method do, Generic Singleton java

Tags: java, generics, singleton

While reading effective java Chapter 5, Item 27

It talks about generic singleton pattern :

> Now suppose that you want to provide an identity function. It would be
>   wasteful to create a new one each time it’s required, as it’s
>   stateless. If generics were reified, you would need one identity
>   function per type, but since they’re erased you need only a generic
>   singleton. Here’s how it looks:

```java
public class GenericSingleton<T> {
    private static UnaryFunction<Object> IDENTIFY_FUNCTION = new UnaryFunction<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(Object args) {
            return args;
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> UnaryFunction<T> identityFunction() {
        return (UnaryFunction<T>) IDENTITY_FUNCTION;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"jute", "hemp", "nylon"};
        UnaryFunction<String> sameString = identityFunction();
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(sameString.apply(s));
        }
        Number[] numbers = {1, 2.0, 3L};
        UnaryFunction<Number> sameNumber = identityFunction();
        for (Number n : numbers) {
            System.out.println(sameNumber.apply(n));
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand what does `apply` method actually do!
It's like getting an object and returning itself. why? some useless sample?

Would someone tell me the use case please ?

Comment: This is an *identity function*, not an *identify* function. Look up the mathematical definition of an identity function.

Comment: @chrylis Thank I read it now and I edited my question, but I have the same question yet. does it have any use case in real programs ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987085/what-do-people-use-the-identity-function-for

Comment: @chrylis all examples are in `haskell` so I guess it's better to keep my question for java examples

Comment: That's why I didn't close it as a duplicate, but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A use case is the [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).

Say you have a list of items identified by a unique key and you want a `Map` from that unique key to the object itself.

`Collectors.toMap()` needs two functions:

- one to extract the key from the object
- another one to extract the value from the object

Since the value should be the object itself, you need a function that takes an object and returns the same object - which is your identity function.